# Smooth shading not working for OBJ loaded in Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

That is, the OBJ looks smooth in my 3D modeling software while looks quirky (triangular) in Three.js scene. I assign MeshLambertMaterial to it. According to the documentation, the default shading for that material is THREE.SmoothShading. Even if I set it manually and check through the debugging console the "shading" property is properly set, the model in the scene still does not look smooth.

Comment: What software are you exporting from? What format? Did you export normals and smoothing groups?

Comment: @2pha I got the model from the Internet and checked it with Cinema 4D. There are already normals in the model which is in standard OBJ format. As for smoothing groups, I don't know what you mean by it because it's one unit, but it looks quite smooth in Cinema 4D when I import it.

Answer (score 4):

The VertexNormals are not calculated by the OBJ(MTL)Loader. You can calculate them afterwards (haven't tested):

```
my3dObject.traverse( function( node ) {
    if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        node.geometry.computeVertexNormals(); 
    }
} );
```

Comment: In my case it seems to be a problem with my model - it has no vertex normals, and has quad faces which are triangulated by the loader. Blender, on the other side, has no problems with this, so it appears to me that the OBJ loader should be more permissive or at least it should have an option for computing the vertex normals because models are often not perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll give it a shot when I'm free and let you know the result. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I cannot find any function named meshN in OBJLoader.js (OBJMTLLoader.js?).

Comment: So you don't have .MTL files and use OBJLoader instead of  OBJMTLLoader. You could search for computeFaceNormals() there and add the fix below that (computeVertexNormals). Another (and maybe much better) solution may be to compute the normals afterwards. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is no computeFaceNormals() invokes in OBJLoader.js. Actually I did already invoke computeVertexNormals() in my script, without which it wouldn't be lit.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.